# Symfony2 Autoloader expected class

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony2 I get an error:

> The autoloader expected class "Website\PublicBundle\Facebook"
>   to be defined in file
>   "C:\PHP-XAMPP\htdocs\myProject/src\Website\PublicBundle\Facebook.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException

I cleared cache, restarted Apache and I tried several solutions from similar questions like this, but nothing works.

**app/config/config.yml:**

```
services:
    facebook:
        class: Website\PublicBundle\Facebook
```

**src/Website/PublicBundle/Facebook.php:**

```
namespace Website\PublicBundle\Facebook;

class Facebook {
    public function __construct() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your namespace should be

```
namespace Website\PublicBundle;
```

Otherwise your class is actually..

```
Website\PublicBundle\Facebook\Facebook
```